# Update Increment If Value is Equal Django

Tags: django, django-models

I'm trying to create a versioning system in django. I want separate versioning per asset name. I've been able to setup a custom increment tool but I can't quite work out how to check what I'm currently trying to create against what's already there. This is the code I currently have:

```py
def next_version():
    latest = Asset.objects.order_by("version").last()

    if not latest:
        return 1

    return latest.version + 1


class Asset(models.Model):
    path = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True, primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    version = models.IntegerField(default=next_version)
    asset_type = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    created_by = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    dependencies = models.JSONField(null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

But the problem I'm having is that the `next_version` function can't read the name of the asset I'm currently trying to create (or at least I think it can't).

So the goal I'm trying to achieve is for the created asset to check the name it's trying to set and if it already exists to bump up the version. Can anyone tell if this is possible?

Edit:
I tried passing the parameter of name to the `next_version` field like so:

```py
def next_version(name):
    latest = Asset.objects.all().order_by("version").last()

    if not latest:
        return 1

    return latest.version + 1


class Asset(models.Model):
    path = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True, primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    version = models.IntegerField(default=next_version(name))
    asset_type = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    created_by = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    dependencies = models.JSONField(null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

This result in the error `NameError: name 'Asset' is not defined`

Thanks,
Mitchell

Comment: The obvious solution is to pass `name` as an argument to the function, and filter the Asset objects to match that name.  So, do that.

Comment: Hmm, when I try and do that I get: `NameError: name 'Asset' is not defined` This happens when I add in the parenthesis.

Comment: "when I add in the parenthesis" -- I have no idea what this means.  Please update your question to show the **actual code**.  Don't make us guess what you tried.

Comment: Also, the original posted code clearly does use the `Asset` object, so again I have no idea what the actual problem is.

Comment: I've updated my original question

Comment: Don't make us guess where the error is.  Please include the full error traceback.

Comment: Also, this is not your full code.  Please include the full code.

Comment: Also, the point of passing `name` as an argument was so that the function could use it to filter the Asset objects.  But you did not add any code to the function to actually use the name argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your next_version function. `.last()` will attempt to return an instance and will raise exception if the queryset is empty. The other issue is your method which is referencing the class comes before the class. You can modify your `next_version` method like below but it would be better you overwrite the `save` method of the `Asset` model as shown at the bottom

```
def next_version(name):
  latest = Asset.objects.all().order_by("version")

  if not latest.exists():
      return 1

  return latest.last().version + 1
```

You can overwrite like this....

```
class Asset(models.Model):
  path = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True, primary_key=True)
  name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
  version = models.IntegerField(default=1)  # Default to 1 initially
  asset_type = models.CharField(max_length=255)
  created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
  created_by = models.CharField(max_length=255)
  dependencies = models.JSONField(null=True)

  def __str__(self):
      return self.name

  def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
      # Check if an asset with the same name already exists
      existing_assets = Asset.objects.filter(name=self.name).order_by('-version')

      if existing_assets.exists():
          # If an asset with the same name exists, increment the version
          self.version = existing_assets.first().version + 1
      else:
          # If it's a new asset, set version to 1
          self.version = 1

      super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```